# What is the probability of rolling an even number and a number greater than 8 for two rolled die?

Tags: probability, dice

This is one of the questions asked in the swirl package of R. One of my students however, has pointed out that the correct option of this question is the wrong answer.

His assertion is that the correct probability is:

18/36 + 10/36 - 6/36 = 22/36

Instead of,

18/36 + 10/36 - 4/36 = 24/36

His point seems correct, since the last term for intersection should be 6/36 buts its showing as 4/36 as the correct option.

Comment: Are you sure your title correctly reflects the question?  The answers would lead one to suspect the question actually was about the event "the sum of the dice is even **or** exceeds 8".

Comment: Reference is to the event for getting an even number and at the same time a number exceeding 8 in the first throw itself.

Comment: Then neither of the answers presented in this question comes even close to giving the correct probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should it be 6/36? There are only four events in the interaction set, $(6, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (4,6)$.
You can check quickly by

```
d1=sample(1:6, 10000, replace=T); d2=sample(1:6, 10000, replace=T)
sum((d1+d2) %% 2 == 0 & d1+d2 > 8) / 10000

> [1] 0.106

6/36
> [1] 0.1666667
4/36
> [1] 0.1111111
```

Answer (score 0):

The student has **in**correctly calculated the answer to the question

> What is the probability that the sum is even **or** greater than $8$?

using the formula  $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ where $A$ is the event that the sum is even ($18$ outcomes) and $B$ the event that the sum is greater than $8$ ($10$ outcomes). As juod's answer points out, the event $A\cap B$ has only $4$ outcomes in it, not $6$ as the student contends and the OP concurs.  Are they possibly thinking of the set
$A\cap B$ as being
$$\left\{(6,6), (6,5), (5,6), (5,5), (6,4), (4,6)\right \} ??$$

What the swirl manual has is the perfectly correct answer to the question highlighted above. *It would be interesting to find out what question the swirl manual is answering*. Is it possible that the OP mistyped the question actually asked in the swirl manual, replacing the **or** by an **and** in the *title*?

Comment: This answer would fit our site's model much better if it were to confine its remarks to the question rather than impugning the capabilities of the OP.  Please reconsider whether you really want this post to remain up.

Comment: @whuber I have edited the post, and would like to have it remain up in its present version. If you feel that it is still inappropriate, please delete it as you have the power to do.

Comment: Thanks, but I needed a clarification to clear out the confusion. I would want to delete the post.

Comment: It is easy to enumerate the number of possible answers which are the 4 possibilities listed in both answers.  Neither answer suggested in the question is correct.

Comment: @MichaelChernick The intersection set suggested by the student was wrong, hence the correction.

Comment: Shiv, I believe @Michael's point is not that the student's suggestion was wrong, but that *both* the student's and the other option are grossly incorrect.  That is what led me to suggest in a separate comment that you might not have correctly described the original question.